# How to make 2 floating divs the same height?

Tags: css

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tier-label">Foo</div>
<div class="tier-row">
    <!-- dynamic drag/drop zone -->
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.tier-label {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tier-row {
    margin-left: 50px;
    min-height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The image shows what I want to do and already got working

[image]

Yet comes the problem:

The right part `tier-row` is drop-zone where one can drop *items* (images). When the space is used it will break and start a new *row*. This works fine. The problem is, that the left part `tier-label` is not growing with it.

How can I adjust my CSS to get the left part growing with the right part?

Comment: Floating is the wrong tool for this sort of thing. Try either `display: flex` or `display: table` (the latter being better supported).

Answer (score 1):

The better solutions is that you should add a **`<div>`** around these two elements. Then give that div `display: table;width:100%` and these elements as `display: table-cell`

```
<div class="tier-wrapper">
    <div class="tier-label">Foo</div>
    <div class="tier-row">
        <!-- dynamic drag/drop zone -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ttfkw5t/6/

Answer (score 1):

I've followed @ralph.m 's suggestion and came up with this solution which was pretty easy

```
.tier-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.tier-label {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tier-row {
    min-height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: That is fine, but -webkit-flex has limited browser support. Please see http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similar issue.  I solved it with jQuery.  Just after the break of the right tier:

```
$(".tier-label").css("height",($(."tier-row").css("height"));
```